# Terminal commandline basics

Tags: command-line, terminal

[image]

Sometimes, actually, it's lowercase. Other times, it has someone else's login. Like it'll be "jdoe" for some reason. Why does it change like that? This is my work computer, if that explains anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about your commandline prompt: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-tip-prompt/

Comment: Does that apply exactly the same to OSX since it looks like that's what OP is using?

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner Yes.